# WPF App Dev with Jetbrains Rider on Mac

Tags: c#, wpf, macos, rider

... is it possible?

And if yes, I started to develop a WPF app on PC with Rider/VS and sometimes want to continue development on my Macbook.

I have Rider on the Macbook and installed .NET Core for Mac according to the info at https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/208074835-Using-Project-Rider-on-Mac-prerequisites

However in Mac Rider the project cannot find dependencies for **PresentationCore** and **PresentationFramework**.

Is it possible to get this working on Mac and if so where do I find these libraries?

Comment: Hi, I also own a MacBook and wanted to know whether it is possible to write the WPF code with Rider on MacOS and then build and run it on windows. I would appreciate your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF is for Windows only - it's in the name *Windows* Presentation Framework. So no.

<strike>And WPF does not run on .NET Core, it runs on the .NET Framework.</strike> Starting with .NET Core 3.0, WPF has been ported to the .NET Core stack.

Comment: Thank you for the info. This is disappointing but makes sense, coming to think of it.

Comment: Starting with .NET Core 3.0, WPF can run on .NET Core, not just .NET Framework. However, it is still Windows only: [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/)